# t-sql query with deep joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm having a little trouble of getting a fast sql-query on this. I've managed to get a query to return the result I want but it takes about 2 sek to run even with the right indexes.

I have these tables:

```
[Login]
loginID
loginTime
userID

[user]
userID 
userName

[companyParticipant]
userID
companyID

[company]
companyID
organisationID
CompanyName
```

What I want to show is all the top 10 latest logins persons with loginTime. Where the user is in a company that I am a participant or a company within the organisations where I am member of a company of that organisation

To get my organisations:

```
SELECT organisationID 
FROM companys 
WHERE companyID IN (
    SELECT companyID 
    FROM companyParticipant 
    WHERE userID = @userID) 
GROUP BY organisationID
```

So what i want i a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 userName, LoginTime 
FROM ....
ORDER BY loginID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT userName, loginTime
      FROM
(
    SELECT u.userName, l.loginTime,
           rn = row_number() over (partition BY u.userName
                              ORDER BY l.loginTime DESC)
      FROM companyParticipant cp
      JOIN companys c ON c.companyID = cp.companyID
      JOIN companys c2 ON c2.organisationID = c.organisationID -- same organisation
      JOIN companyParticipant cp2 ON cp2.companyID = c2.companyID -- participants of same org
      JOIN login l ON l.userID = cp2.userID
      JOIN [user] u ON u.userID = l.userID
     WHERE cp.userID = @userID
)          X
     WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY loginTime DESC
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that it needs to be unique users in the top 10 result

Comment: really appriate the help I'm getting. I cant get this query to run fast it takes 2-3 seconds to run.

Answer (score 0):

This query goes under a second and is superfast. Seems strange
no need for tiebreaking either beacuase there is always people logging in and a new login must be 10 minutes apart otherwise it just updates the last login.

```
SELECT      TOP (10) l.loginID, l.loginTime,u.userName
FROM          logins AS l WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                        users AS u WITH(NOLOCK) ON l.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE      (l.UserID <> @userID)
AND u.userID IN(SELECT u.userID FROM companyParticipants AS sp2 WHERE sp2.companyID IN (SELECT sc2.companyID FROM company AS sc2 WHERE sc2.organisationID IN(
SELECT sc.organisationID FROM company AS sc LEFT JOIN companyParticipants AS sp ON sc.companyID = sp.companyID WHERE sp.userID = @userID AND sc.organisationID > 0 GROUP BY sc.organisationID
)))
ORDER BY l.loginID DESC
```